# Why static reference of a class giving Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, oop

Here I have two classes. When I tried to access method of A class using static reference, it is giving the **Null pointer exception**. Why is this happening??

**A.Java**

```
public class A{
  int a;
  public void getA(){
    a=11;
    System.out.println("a"+a);
  }
}
```

**C.java**

```
public class C{
  static A ref;
  public static void main(String args[]){
    ref.getA();
}
}
```

The problem arises when i'm executing C.

Comment: you never create an instance for A

Comment: You should read more about how to use "static". Simply saying "static A ref" doesn't mean you can access A in a static way.

Comment: `static` here means, that you can get to `ref` without having an instance of `C` (i.e. you can write `C.ref` instead of `new C().ref`. It doesn't mean that `ref` refers to an instance of `A` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
static A ref;
```

This has nothing to do with `static` keyword. You're not initializing `A`, and the default value for objects is `null`, so you're actually writing:

```
ref.getA();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not instantiated the Object `ref`

You need to do

```
A ref = new A ();
```